# Access - pass parameter from one query to another

Tags: sql, ms-access, parameter-passing

In Access 2016, I would like to run a query (SSC_County) where the results will be exported as an xls. The goal is to have one column in the xls for the date coupled with each STATE_STATUSID value for an APD as follows. The common ID is:

```
dbo_APD.ID = dbo_APD_Tracking.APDID = WY_APD_STATUS.APDID
```

And I'm after each WY_APD_STATUS.Status_date in the xls.

Here are the key pieces of SSC_County:

```
SELECT dbo_APD.ID, dbo_APD_Tracking.Project_area_name, WY_APD_STATUS.Status_date
FROM WY_APD_STATUS RIGHT JOIN (dbo_APD INNER JOIN dbo_APD_Tracking ON dbo_APD.ID = dbo_APD_Tracking.APDID) ON WY_APD_STATUS.APDID = dbo_APD.ID
WHERE ((dbo_APD_Tracking.Project_area_name="Fake project") AND [STATE_STATUSID]=6);
```

I've tried having a subquery that accepts a parameter, [STATE_STATUSID]; here's it's SQL:

```
SELECT s.Status_date, s.APDID
FROM dbo_ST_APD_SUBMITTAL_STATUS AS s INNER JOIN dbo_APD AS a ON s.APDID = a.ID
WHERE s.State_statusID=[STATE_STATUSID];
```

So if I run this query from Design View I get a prompt for [STATE_STATUSID] and I can enter in an integer as expected.

The above SQL for SSC_County doesn't actually pass a parameter to the subquery... Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Please show outer query.

Comment: This reads as the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You are caught up in *your* solution to a problem we do not know about. Step back and give us the full picture. What is the overall objective? How is query being run? What are the numbers being passed multiple times? Please edit post accordingly.

Comment: Post edited accordingly.

Comment: I've simplified the question as much as possible here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51678472/access-retrieving-status-and-date-puzzle